# Azure Search Design Question: Omit result if User has seen this result

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to design a solution where I don't have to use the SQL Server Database to answer a question: Show me Azure Index search results where the user has never seen this search result.

I can keep track of user document "views" in my SQL database, but how do I extend this functionality to Azure Search Index queries?

I mean I could do a $filter where document id is not in (1,2,3,etc), or I could filter the Index results before the user ever sees them from the server.

I'm just wondering if there's a more clever way to do this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is that for a certain time period after which the results should surface back up? How many users are you expecting to use this system?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to achieve this is the first option you mentioned, once the first query comes on that user session, you can save which document ids were returned and then create a filter to exclude those ids for subsequent queries on the same session.